Speech_recognition error, "object has no attribute 'recognize_google'"
I'm trying to use speech_recognition on my RaspberryPi 2, but when I run this code:
import speech_recognition as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    string = ""
    audio = r.listen(source)
    string = r.recognize_google(audio)
print(string)

I get this error:
AtrributeError: 'Recognizer' object has no attribute 'recognize_google'

I added this line of code as recommended here:
from speech_recognition.recognizers import google, whisper

and I get this error:
ImportError: cannot import name 'NotRequired' from 'typing_extentions'

I have installed typing_extentions and it says it's already installed, but I don't understand what this error means, nor could I find how to fix it.

are you using a virtual environment for Python? what is the output of pip list?

No, I am not using a virtual environment, just Geanny which already comes on the Raspberry Pi. It won't let me paste in the whole result for pip list since it is too long, but SpeechRecognition 3.10.0 is in the list it gives me. This same exact code works on my laptop but when I run it on my Pi it doesn't.

So your RPi and your computer run two different operating systems, and the binary packages are different for each of them. This will be a package installation problem. What version of typing_extensions do you have installed (pip list will show you), and is that compatible with speech_recognition? Often these problems are all to do with package dependencies.

Thank you so much for your help, I updated the typing_extensions and SpeechRecognition packages, and now it works perfectly. Not sure why I didn't think of that.

You're welcome! Glad it's working for you!
